# How does hit chance and damage work in Warhammer Quest?

Tags: warhammer-quest

I've started playing Warhammer Quest for iOS and I seem to be missing with my attacks a lot. I see stats on my character sheet called called "Ballistic Skill" and "Weapon Skill" and I assume they somehow govern my chance to hit with ranged or melee attacks, but I don't understand how. Likewise, I see that weapons have a damage range, such as 5-7, which I assume means it does a base of 5-7 damage. But I've also seen weapons that say something like "4-6 damage, not affected by strength", which leads me to believe that Strength normally affects damage somehow.

How does this all work? Do Weapon and Ballistic skill play into hit chance, damage, or both? Is there some sort of Dodge stat that they're compared against? And how do Strength and Toughness play into this?

I'm trying to get a better sense of how these stats work so that I can make informed decisions about the gear I find, so while I definitely need to know the basics of what the different stats affect, I'd also appreciate seeing some hard numbers so I can quantify how much I might expect boosting my Elf's Ballistic Skill by 1 might actually help versus choosing some other upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I found some of this information buried in the help.

Melee attack hit chance is based in comparing both combatant's weapon skills. If they are even, it is a 50/50 chance. It doesn't say how much the odds change as they start to differ, though.

Melee attacks do damage equal to a chararacter's strength, plus any bonuses (such as weapon damage), minus the defenders toughness. So Strength is +1 damage per point and Toughness is -1 damage per point.

Ranged attacks do not have Strength added in to the damage.

I have not found information on what Ballistic Skill is compared against to determine hit chance.

Comment: I don't know if they straight ported over the their table top rules, but typically BS and WS are treated as such in their games library:  BS 1 is 6+ to hit, 2 is 5+, 3 is 4+, 4 is 3+ and 5 is 2+.    For WS, it is indeed a 4+ when even.  If your skill is higher you hit on a 3+.  If the opposing skill is double + 1 then you hit on a 5+.   All rolls are made on a single d6.